# React Native Drawer Navigation Reanimated Problem

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I try to use drawer navigator on react native, first i have installed all necessary packages and i am using reanimated-1 but app can not be built and gives this error. If i try to use reanimated-2 everything is fine but while i am using reanimaed-1 i am getting this error.

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\fikre\Desktop\reactnative\drawerNavDemo\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build.gradle' line: 64
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.

> Configuration with name 'compile' not found.